# Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 won't connect to WPA PSK or WPA PEAP. WEP and open works. 14.04LTS

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, network-manager, iwlwifi

Cliffs: Can't get this to work with WPA PSK or WPA PEAP. Same laptop (Dell Latitude E6410) with a no-name USB Wifi dongle works fine connecting to the same networks. I realize this hardware is known to be buggy with 802.11n so I disabled it and got the same results. I also tried the `system_certs` trick and that didn't make any difference either.

tl;dr:

```
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN, REV=0x74
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 9.221.4.1 build 25532 op_mode iwldvm
```

Tried all three firmware blobs on kernel.org, no change in behavior.

Syslog during connection attempt for WPA PEAP:

```
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'MyNetwork' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul 16 10:54:45  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: get_secret_flags: assertion 'is_secret_prop (setting, secret_name, error)' failed
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'MyNetwork' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyNetwork'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'password' value '<omitted>'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1300'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'identity' value 'username@MyNetwork.com'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jul 16 10:55:04  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jul 16 10:55:04  wpa_supplicant[1488]: message repeated 4 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Jul 16 10:55:07  wpa_supplicant[1488]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx (SSID='MyNetwork' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 16 10:55:07  kernel: [ 1851.996119] wlan0: authenticate with 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx
Jul 16 10:55:07  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 16 10:55:07  kernel: [ 1852.036087] wlan0: direct probe to 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
Jul 16 10:55:07  kernel: [ 1852.237367] wlan0: direct probe to 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
Jul 16 10:55:07  kernel: [ 1852.441249] wlan0: direct probe to 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx (try 3/3)
Jul 16 10:55:07  kernel: [ 1852.645135] wlan0: authentication with 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx timed out
Jul 16 10:55:08  wpa_supplicant[1488]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MyNetwork" auth_failures=1 duration=10
Jul 16 10:55:08  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jul 16 10:55:18  wpa_supplicant[1488]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jul 16 10:55:18  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 16 10:55:18  wpa_supplicant[1488]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="MyNetwork"
Jul 16 10:55:23  wpa_supplicant[1488]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jul 16 10:55:26  wpa_supplicant[1488]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx (SSID='MyNetwork' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 16 10:55:26  kernel: [ 1870.763176] wlan0: authenticate with 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx
Jul 16 10:55:26  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 16 10:55:26  kernel: [ 1870.772886] wlan0: direct probe to 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
Jul 16 10:55:26  kernel: [ 1870.975037] wlan0: direct probe to 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
Jul 16 10:55:26  kernel: [ 1871.178935] wlan0: direct probe to 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx (try 3/3)
Jul 16 10:55:26  kernel: [ 1871.382792] wlan0: authentication with 8c:0c:90:xx:xx:xx timed out
Jul 16 10:55:26  wpa_supplicant[1488]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MyNetwork" auth_failures=2 duration=20
Jul 16 10:55:26  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jul 16 10:55:29  NetworkManager[1041]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
Jul 16 10:55:29  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [50 120 53]
Jul 16 10:55:29  NetworkManager[1041]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'MyNetwork'
Jul 16 10:55:29  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 16 10:55:29  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Jul 16 10:55:29  wpa_supplicant[1488]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jul 16 10:55:32  NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```